# Hierarchical URLs in Django

Tags: django

Is there a way to implement hierarchical query pattern in Django? As far as I know, the framework only allows to route to views by parsing URLs of a specific format, like:

```
/customers/{order} -> customer.views.show_orders(order)
```

But what if I need something like this:

```
/book1/chapter1/section1/paragraph1/note5 -> notes.view.show(note_id)
```

where note_id is the id of the last part of the URL, but the URL could have different number of components:

```
/book1/chapter1
/book1/chapter1/section1
etc.
```

Each time, it would point to the relevant part of the book depth depending on the depth. Is this doable?

I know there is this: https://github.com/MrKesn/django-mptt-urls, but I am wondering if there is another solution. This isn't ideal for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django URLs are just regular expressions, so the simplest way would be to just ignore everything prior to the "note" section of the URL. For example:

```
url(r'^.*/note(?P<note_id>[0-9]+)$', 'notes.view.show'),
```

However, this would ignore the book, chapter, paragraph components. Which would mean your notes would need unique ids across the system, not just within the book. If you needed to capture any number of the interim parts it would be more complicated.

I can't confirm this will work right now, but using non-capture groups in regular expressions, you should be able to capture an optional book and chapter like so:

```
url(r'^(?:book(?P<book_id>[0-9]+)/)?(?:chapter(?P<chapter_id>[0-9]+)/)?note(?P<note_id>[0-9]+)$', 'notes.view.show'),
```

Comment: I was thinking along the same line of thought as I was waiting for someone to reply. I think I can just do this: url(r'^.*/$', notes.views.show, name='show'). Then inside the view, I will parse the content of request.path to see not only what is the last node ID, but also the entire path in terms of node IDs. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @pkout I'd recommend not, [URLs are a part of the user interface](http://www.kidstrythisathome.com/2010/10/urls-should-be-meaningful/) as much as anything else. Consider how they are structured as that will impact your design as much as anything else.

Comment: Yeah, the URL shouldn't contain IDs. It should contain slugs, but then I can parse the path.url in the view and extract the slugs from there. That preserves search engines friendly URLs and gives me freedom of depth simultaneously. Right?

Comment: Also, Django looks for a matching URL pattern in the order in which the patterns appear in urls.py, so if I put the above pattern as last, it should never collide with any other pattern.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with IDs in a URL, but having a predictable set of URLs will give the site structure. Is freedom of depth what you really want? If you just want the note id and the rest is fluid or adds nothing, why not just capture `example.com/note/1234`?

Comment: Don't create a view in `view.py` that will parse extra parts out of the path, use `urls.py` as intended.

Comment: Yeah, I should never need anything but the last node in the URL. That should simplify things. Thanks for your thoughts on this!

Comment: @pkout If the answer helped answer your question you can indicate so by clicking the green tick.

Answer (score 0):

Use named groups to accomplish this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups

```
url(r'^book(?P<book_id>\d+)/chapter(?P<chapter_id>\d+)/section(?P<section_id>\d+)/paragraph(?P<paragraph_id>\d+)/note(?P<note_id>\d+)$', notes.view.show(book_id, chapter_id, section_id, paragraph_id, note_id)
```

Comment: This isn't ideal because it presets a set hierarchy depth. My hierarchy level is of an unknown depth. I guess I could just create a very long chain of these named groups. I think parsing the content in the view to be independent of depth might be a better solution. Thanks for your help, though!

Answer (score 0):

For those who really need a variable-depth URL structure and need the URL to consist strictly of slugs, not IDs, knowing all the components of the URL is critical to retrieve the correct record from the database. Then, the only solution I can think of is using:

```
 url(r'^.*/$', notes.views.show, name='show')
```

and then parsing the content of the URL to get the individual components after retrieving the URL in the view using the `request.path` call. This doesn't sound ideal, but it is a way to accomplish it.